# How do I slide content?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```js
$(".step-button").bind("click", function() {
  var step = $(this).attr("data-target-class");
  $(".step").removeClass("active");
  $("." + step).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.step {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.active {
  height: auto;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="step step1 active">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button class="step-button btn-primary" data-target-class="step2">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="step step2">
  <p>Hello World 2</p>
  <button class="step-button btn-primary" data-target-class="step3">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="step step3">
  <p>Hello World 3</p>
  <button class="step-button btn-primary " data-target-class="step4">Submit</button>
</div>
<div class="step step4">
  <p>Thank you</p>
  <button class="step-button btn-primary " data-target-class="step1">start 
    again</button>
</div>
```

So I have 3 different paragraphs with next buttons. I want to keep only one visible at a time. Upon clicking next the second paragraph and button should slide in, and in the end the last one.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Edit: So I have achieved this, and leaving for someone else, if they need for future reference.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I wanted to know if the sliding part can be done via CSS?

Comment: Yes, it can (although the on-click interactivity might be best initiated/handled with JavaScript). Have you made a start? Can you share your best attempt and describe how that attempt failed, and in what way it failed? Please see the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines, then [edit] your question to include the relevant code and details.

Comment: Not started yet. Do not know how to start. Really looking for a small start, so I can pick up from there. Any leads? Will be much appreciated

Comment: Did you take a look at the [Bootstrap 4 Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)?